# Kill my application while it's using a threaded dll call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a structural problem resulting in an `System.ObjectDisposedException` with a dll.

More specifically it's a µEye Camera driver that is advised to capture data from a camera. I got two events from this camera that are fired asynchronously:

- OnFrameEvent
- OnSequenceEvent

The latter tells me that my capture is beeing completed and I can continue in saving my images.

This is the code that does the work:

```
private void onSequenceEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;
    SequenceCount++;

    Camera.Acquisition.Stop();

    int s32SeqID;
    statusRet = Camera.Memory.Sequence.GetLast(out s32SeqID);

    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Save Images...";
        this.pbCapture.Value = 0;
    });

    Rectangle src = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle dst = new Rectangle();           

    src.X = AOI_Size.X;
    src.Y = AOI_Size.Y;
    src.Width = AOI_Size.Width;
    src.Height = AOI_Size.Height;

    dst.X = 0; dst.Y = 0; dst.Width = AOI_Size.Width; dst.Height = AOI_Size.Height;

    Bitmap bitmap_source = new Bitmap(MySensorInfo.MaxSize.Width, MySensorInfo.MaxSize.Height);;
    Bitmap bitmap_destination = new Bitmap(dst.Width, dst.Height);;

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap_destination);

    for (int i = 1; i < s32SeqID; i++)
    {
        Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(i, out bitmap_source);

        g.DrawImage(bitmap_source, dst, src, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        bitmap_destination.Save(PathToSave + i.ToString() + ".bmp");

        this?.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            pbOverallProgress.Value++;
            pbCapture.Value++;
        });

    }

    bitmap_source.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();

    this.CloseForm?.Invoke(1);
}
```

However - as you may expect the `Invoke` call will cause the `ObjectDisposedException` as the "Cancel"-Button is beeing pressed:

```
this?.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
{
    pbOverallProgress.Value++;
    pbCapture.Value++;
});
```

Here's the code of the Cancel-Button:

```
private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to cancel?", "Abort", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.CloseForm?.Invoke(0);
    }
}

private void UEye_Dialog_Form_CloseForm(int exitCode)
{
    this?.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        if (Camera != null)
        {
            Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEvent;
            Camera.EventSequence -= onSequenceEvent;
        }

        Camera?.Acquisition.Stop();

        Camera = null;

        ReturnCode = exitCode;

        this.Close();
    });
}
```

`UEye_Dialog_Form_CloseForm(int exitCode)` is a event where `CloseForm` is it's delegate.

I hope this was not too much information :)

This exception only occure if the image is beeing saved, not if I'm waiting for the sequence to be captured.

Sure I could pack the UI Update code within a try-catch-block or check if the forms state is Disposed/Disposing. But for my little programming skills it looks like a structural problem.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is that you're doing multi-threading without synchronization.

`Invoke` presents one such synchronization point, which is fine. However, as you've found out, it doesn't work after the handle is disposed - this makes perfect sense; `Invoke` simply sends a window message to the given handle, and when the handle no longer exists there's noöne to deal with the message (not to mention what would `Close` (which just sends `WM_CLOSE` etc.) do when the window no longer exists).

Solving this is quite tricky, actually. Even if you check if the form is disposed before trying the `Invoke`, it might still be disposed between the check and the `Invoke` itself. `lock`ing would allow you to handle the synchronization, but you'd need to `lock` in `DestroyHandle` or perhaps an event like `Closing` - the key is to make sure that whatever signal you send is safely tied to whether `Invoke` is safe right now. Of course, you don't really want to use `Invoke` - you need `BeginInvoke`, otherwise you're guaranteed to have a deadlock when `Invoke` needs to wait for the UI thread which is currently waiting for the lock to be released. Not good :)

Being prepared for an `ObjectDisposedException` might be the best solution. But looking through the reference source code, it doesn't look like it's 100% correct either - it's consistent on a single thread, but you're not calling `Invoke` on the UI thread (obviously).

Comment: Hi Luaan, thanks for your answer. Actually besides `btn_Exit_Click` any code runs in another thread created by the dll that I'm using.

Comment: @AllDayPiano Except for the `Invoke`d parts, which is exactly the point. You need to ensure that the window still exists in a thread-safe way before you can do the `Invoke` - and that requires synchronization between whatever thread you're on right now and the UI thread.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. Pretty clear if I think about it! I think there might be some good input on SO how to solve this. But thanks for your help. This is some great hint!